# Reshape data into long format by expanding two times, first, by "year" and then by "month"

Tags: r, panel, reshape, melt

I have data of a lot of villages with unique identifiers (village), I am trying to shape the data into a long format by first expanding by year and then by month.

```
df_input <- data.frame( village=c("A","B","C"), population = c(1000,1500,2000))    


df_output <- data.frame(year= c(2001,2001,2001,2002,2002,2002,2003,2003,2003),
                        month = c("1","2","3","1","2","3","1","2","3"),
                        village = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"), 
                        population = c (1000, 1000,1000,1500,1500,1500,2000,2000,2000))
```

I am using the following code to first expan it by the year:

```
df_panel <- df_input %>%
  merge(expand.grid(year=2001:2003, key=.$key), by="code_2011")
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Error in fix.by(by.y, y) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to create a *cross join* or *cartesian merge* of

- the years `2001:2003`,
- the months `1:3`, and
- each row of `df_input`.

There are several methods to achieve this, e.g.,

```
merge(list(year = 2001:2003), merge(list(month = 1:3), df_input))
```

> ```
>    year month village population
> 1  2001     1       A       1000
> 2  2002     1       A       1000
> 3  2003     1       A       1000
> 4  2001     2       A       1000
> 5  2002     2       A       1000
> 6  2003     2       A       1000
> 7  2001     3       A       1000
> 8  2002     3       A       1000
> 9  2003     3       A       1000
> 10 2001     1       B       1500
> 11 2002     1       B       1500
> 12 2003     1       B       1500
> 13 2001     2       B       1500
> 14 2002     2       B       1500
> 15 2003     2       B       1500
> 16 2001     3       B       1500
> 17 2002     3       B       1500
> 18 2003     3       B       1500
> 19 2001     1       C       2000
> 20 2002     1       C       2000
> 21 2003     1       C       2000
> 22 2001     2       C       2000
> 23 2002     2       C       2000
> 24 2003     2       C       2000
> 25 2001     3       C       2000
> 26 2002     3       C       2000
> 27 2003     3       C       2000
> ```

or using `expand.grid()` and `merge()`:

```
merge(expand.grid(year = 2001:2003, month = 1:3), df_input)
```

which returns the same result as above.